# Какой знак препинания поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания следует поставить перед "не опасен" в следующем предложении:

"Кто любит блины (...) не опасен". В сети видела вариант с запятой, но мне кажется, что можно использовать тире. Ваше мнение?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь следует поставить запятую и тире как единый знак, так как пропущено указательное слово ТОТ: "Кто любит блины, - не опасен".

Сравнить: "Кто любит блины, тот не опасен".

ПРАВИЛО

Запятая и тире  как единый знак обозначают увеличенную паузу после ряда однородных придаточных или при пропуске союза.

Похожий пример: "Едва только раздались первые выстрелы, – ожила безлюдная степь, над которой уже смыкалась в далеких тучах щель заката".Здесь пропуск второй части двойного союза  ЕДВА…КАК.

Comment: София, Ваш вариант мне ближе: именно это подразумеваемое "тот" не давало покоя))). Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

По правилам, конечно, здесь нужна запятая между частями сложноподчиненного предложения, но вполне возможно интонационное тире для подчеркивания мысли "не опасен". Розенталь приводит такое правило для случаев, когда придаточное изъяснительное (реже условное) стоит впереди главного предложения (Кто весел - тот смеется). Предлагаемые в этом случае запятая и тире не могут быть использованы, так как такой двойной знак, как справедливо отмечала София, употребляется в так называемом периоде, когда главному предложению предшествуют несколько придаточных изъяснительных или условных. В приведенном же предложении только одно придаточное, и вместо запятой ставится тире. Подробно см. Розенталя, раздел "Сложноподчиненные предложения"

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!